# Change background color of cells based on same values in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to change the background colour of certain cells in sheet 1 based on the same set of values in the sheet 2.

I want it to search the values in sheet 2 to sheet 1, if the values are same then the colour should change according to whatever color code we give. Below are screenshots of sheet1 (green) where I want to apply formatting and other is sheet2 is where I give input

I have got this code below, but it is selecting the cells in which data is not available also, please explain.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tmpSO()

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("A1:B10")
        If cell.Value2 <> Sheet2.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).Value2 Then
            cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

@Peh , please check the below screenshot for how exactly my out put should look like in sheet1 based on the values in sheet2.

Output (Sheet1)

[image]

Input (Sheet2)

[image]

Comment: Please tell me the code you have tried and what the result of that code was

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change background color of range of cells based on the range of cells in an another sheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971847/how-to-change-background-color-of-range-of-cells-based-on-the-range-of-cells-in)

Comment: `If SomeValuesMatchInAnotherSheet() Then Cells.Interior.Color = vbRed` happy coding!

Comment: @RevanErraboina Please edit your original post to include the code - don't post it as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working fine. In sheet 1 it colors every cell of `Range("A1:B10")` that is different from sheet 2. If you don't want empty cells of sheet 1 to be colored you need to check for empty cells too.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tmpSO()

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Sheet1.Range("A1:B10")
        If cell.Value2 <> Sheet2.Cells(cell.Row, cell.Column).Value2 And _
           cell.Value2 <> vbNullString Then
            cell.Interior.Color = vbRed
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

---

Update for the updated question:
Therefore you will need a second loop. The first loop loops through the cells you want to format, the second loop loops through the input values and compares them to every cell of the first loop.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub tmpSO()
    Dim iCell As Range, jCell As Range

    Dim FormatRange As Range
    Set FormatRange = Sheet1.Range("A1:H11") 'the range you want to format

    Dim InputRange As Range
    Set InputRange = Sheet2.Range("B4:B10") 'the range where your input values are

    For Each iCell In FormatRange
        For Each jCell In InputRange

            If iCell.Value2 = Sheet2.Cells(jCell.Row, jCell.Column).Value2 And _
               iCell.Value2 <> vbNullString Then 'compare cell with all input values but left out empty cells
                iCell.Interior.Color = vbRed
                Exit For ' we can abort compairing with other input values if one is found.
            End If

        Next jCell
    Next iCell

End Sub
```

Comment: This worked sir. But, When I removed 2 numbers in sheet2 and run the code, its still showing the old out put by coloring the numbers which are not in sheet2. Eg: I have 1, 2 ,3, 4, 5 in sheet 1 and 1, 2 ,3, 4, 5 in sheet 2 when I ran the code first time it worked but when I removed 5  from sheet 2 and clear format in sheet 1and run the code , its still showing the old put by selecting the range until 5 in sheet 1. Please help.

Comment: Your code does not remove the red color. You need to remove the color of all cells first. You can learn how to do that by using the [macro recorder](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automate-tasks-with-the-Macro-Recorder-974ef220-f716-4e01-b015-3ea70e64937b) and doing it manually.

Comment: I did remove the color manually, but still showing the same result. I might sound confusing but, All I need is that there is sheet1 in which values are distributed scatteringly and then there is a C colomn sheet2 where I give input of values. Macro should be able to identify the values in sheet1 based on values in sheet2 and change the colrs in Sheet1. I have shared the screenshots in question, please check.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you show a screenshot how the result should look like?

Comment: I have attached the screenshots of the output and input in original question.Please check.

Comment: Therefore you need two loops. See my updated answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138934/discussion-between-revan-erraboina-and-peh).